# copying cell formats in excel VBA

Tags: excel

I have a code that filters a data and copy the required rows on new sheet based on condition. What I also want is to copy the cells formatting. Im using the following code:

Can someone please tell me where did I go wrong with the formatting part? the filter part works perfectly.

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()

Dim wsFU As Worksheet
Dim wsTD As Worksheet

Set wsFU = Worksheets("Follow Up")
Set wsTD = Worksheets("Today")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wsTD.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

a = wsFU.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
wsFU.AutoFilterMode = False

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = "Today"
Set wsTD = Worksheets("Today")

    With wsFU.Range("A2:P" & a) 'adjust to  end of date column
        .AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=Format(Date, "mm/dd/yy")
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=wsTD.Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    End With
wsFU.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm going to guess since you used `Destination:=` in `.Copy`, it's not necessarily going to work the same with `.PasteSpecial`.  Try ending the line with `.Copy`, then on the next line, `With wsTD.Range("A1") // .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths // .. etc // end with`?

Comment: It’s setting the formatting right but not copying the data from filter. It just pastes the header row